# C# params keyword and function overloading

Tags: c#, parameters, overloading

In .net framework I constantly see overloaded functions like the following,

1. `public void Log(string message)`...
2. `public void Log(string message, params object[] args)`...

my question is since the params keyword allows zero or more parameters, could we just get rid of the first signature? With just the second signature, I could call it with no parameters fine like below, so I don't know why they would have the first signature?

```
Log("calling with no param");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another reason is `params` is slow, thinking that all parameters are collected and an array is built. So the second one is slower.

```
public static string Format(string format, object arg0);
public static string Format(string format, params object[] args);
```

Comment: Jeffrey Richter, in his book [CLR via C#](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780735627048) goes into this in more detail; essentially you're right, it's an optimization to avoid unnecessary array overheads (construction, access & garbage collection).

Comment: @Bevan: I got to know this from his book, too :)

Comment: Note that if you call `Format("foo", null)` the second version of the function will be called, with `args == null`.

Answer (score 2):

This pattern is typically used if the array-less version has a simpler implementation.

Answer (score 2):

There is a small speed advantage as well.

Milliseconds taken for 1 billion iterations of calling a very simple (`count++`) method with each:

- 2472 ms w/o `params`
- 7773 ms w/ `params`